# Need date time formatting help

Tags: apex, datetime

This code `record.Start_Time__c.time()` is giving me `11:30:00.000Z` but I just want `11:30am` or pm or army time might be ok too.

This code `currStartDate.Date()` is giving me `2015-07-08 00:00:00` but I just want `2015-07-08`

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Java SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
system.debug(Datetime.now().format('hh:mmaa')); // 08:24AM
system.debug(Datetime.now().format('hh:mm:ss aa')); // 08:24:07 AM 
system.debug(Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd'));  // 2016-05-31
```

Note that these are methods on `Datetime`, so you should not call `date()` or `time()` on your `Datetime` value before doing the formatting, as doing so will change the type to `Date` or `Time` respectively, and neither of these types have a `format` method defined`.

Comment: It won't allow me to do this record.Start_Time__c.time().format('hh:mm:ss aa')

Comment: @ApexN-u-b It's a method on `Datetime`, not `Time`. Remove the call to `time()`.

Comment: My apologies. I saw victors answer and just pasted it in before I saw your explanation.  You were correct. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use below lines,

```
record.Start_Time__c.format('hh:mm a');    //11:30 AM
currStartDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd');        //2015-07-08
```

Comment: How is this even different from my answer?